# how to move logs from log storages (_Default) to cloud storage for specific filter query in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have been trying to move data from log storage to cloud storage using below steps

**STEP 1**.Added Query in the below location with specfic timestamp (for 2 days before)

[image: enter code here]

**STEP 2** : Created a sink from clicking create sink as shown in below
[image]

**STEP 3**: Added storage details in the sink as shown below

[image]

The data is not being added to storage though. Can someone please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sink that you configure is only for the new logs. You can't sink the existing logs.

You can list and save the logs in Cloud Storage by yourselves by using the [rest API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list)